# Checkmarx DOM XSS Vulnerability flagging JS/jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss, checkmarx

From what I've been able to find online, I think Checkmarx is flagging because the code is appending HTML content directly to the DOM using .append() which may include user-controlled input. To fix this I used jQuery.text() to safely set the content of the  element and createTextNode() to safely add the value as text to ensure that k and v will not be parsed as HTML but instead as plain text.

I was expecting these changes to resolve the issue; however, these changes did not resolve the issue for Checkmarx. I'm not really familiar with JS and jQuery so any help is appreciated.

Original Code:

```
$.each(response, function(k, v) {
    $("#ulId").append("<li class='list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope'><strong class='ng-binding'>"+k+": </strong>"+v+"</li>");             
});
```

Changes:

```
$.each(response, function(k, v) {
        var li = $("<li></li>").addClass('list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope');
    var strong = $("<strong></strong>").addClass('ng-binding').text(k + ": ");
    li.append(strong);
    li.append(document.createTextNode(v));
    $("#ulId").append(li)
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Problem: Checkmarx scan summary is returning a Client_DOM_Stored_XSS vulnerability. Original code listed is what the scan is saying is vulnerable. How can I resolve the vulnerability? The changes I made do not resolve it